# Is the window.System object a required part of JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, specifications, ecmascript-6

A while back I read that the System object is a required part of es6 modules, basically a new Object type with all the required semantics for module loading.

Is this a strict es6 requirement? It doesn't seem to be in the latest spec.

Comment: Could you please link to the site that you found saying this? Googling it mainly brings up results that seem like it’s an unapproved proposal, I think.

Comment: @Xufox it was part pf the spec until [October 2014](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts#august_24_2014_draft_rev_27).

Comment: note that your question title is misleading, because `window` is specific to page contexts in browsers. In other contexts (browser addons) or completely different javascript environments the global objects do not have to accessible through a named variable called `window`. Afaik it's not required to be accessible at all except through the top level `this` or things bound to it.

Comment: This may be of interest and why kangax removed modules from compat table.  https://github.com/kangax/compat-table/issues/316

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The global `System` object is not part of ES2015.

The module loading API, which includes `System`, was removed from the ES2015 spec in [Draft 28, October 2014](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts#october_14_2014_draft_rev_28).

Module loading is now tracked by the separate [WhatWG loader spec](https://github.com/whatwg/loader).

There is an implementation of the module loader API as specified in Draft 27 (including `System`) at https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the API was dropped from *ES2015*, but will eventually be implemented.

I found [this](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#module-loaders) repository on GitHub, which talks a bit about the Module Loader API, but if you look at the issues, the first one is named *"[Programmatic module loader API Specification?](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features/issues/75)"*. It includes a conversation on the subject.

The first comment says this:

> The module loader API was actually removed from ES2015; it should
>   probably just be removed from this repo.

And this is also an interesting comment from there:

> Worse, there's no way for import to even load modules, since it
>   doesn't have a loader to consult.
>
> Eventually there will be a loader spec, but until then ES2015 just
>   specifies the syntax, and the syntax does nothing. (That is, the spec
>   contains points where it's like "consult the host environment to do
>   something useful here.")

The person who made both of the previous comments, links to these notes as a reference:

https://github.com/tc39/tc39-notes/blob/master/es6/2014-09/sept-25.md#loader-pipeline

> **Conclusion/Resolution**
>
> Loader pipeline goes into a separate spec: living document that deals
>   with integration